# How to view equation of Polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

**Can you help me view the equation of the curve in this plot? I need the equation to predict the data for 2022. (the equation doesn't have to be in the graph, you can just print it)**

**I would also like the dots to be shown. The dots meaning the data points in the graph. It seems that the curve has hidden the dots. And I would also like to view stuff like y-intercept, slope value and etc.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using numpy.polyfit for that.

example data:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = -1.5 * x ** 2 + 4 * x + 10
```

use

```
np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
```

output:

```
array([-1.5,  4. , 10. ])
```